# Wordpress seo by yoast nofollow

Tags: wordpress, seo

Set up nofollow option in "Meta Robots Follow" setting for one single page on advanced tab of metabox, but do not see any changes. How does it work?

site.com/robots.txt didn't changed:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /wp-includes/
```

also do not see any nofollow meta tags in page source.

Answer (score 0):

With this setting, you should see the following code in the page's source: 
`<meta name="robots" content="index,nofollow"/>` (if the Meta Robots Index set to index).

Try the followings:

- Take a look at the page's source in incognito mode
- Make sure your WordPress version is compatible with the plugin (3.8
  or higher)
- If it is, make sure you have the latest version of the plugin